# Tableau Number of days since last invoice

Tags: tableau-api, date-arithmetic

I have Tableau data which consists of Customer Name and Invoice Date.

Cust 1 - 01/01/2014
Cust 1 - 05/01/2014
Cust 2 - 10/02/2014
Cust 2 - 20/03/2014
etc.

I want to find the number of days since the last invoice for each customer and display the data in a table as follows:

Customer | # of days since last invoice
Cust 1      | 170 days 
Cust 2      | 110 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the customer field in the rows shelf,

Create a calculated field like this

DATEDIFF('day',MAX([InvoiceDate]),NOW())

Drag this calculated field to the TEXT mark.